# Eliminating embedded time periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a table containing data for different services divided into time periods, meaning every row has a start date and an end date. Some of the services are the same.

I am looking for a solution on how to remove embedded periods of the same service, meaning all periods contained in or similar to another period having the same service. In the following example I want to remove rn 2 and 3 as their periods are embedded in rn 1:

[image]

Comment: Can you post an example of what you have and what you want?

Comment: If two periods overlap (assuming I understand what you're asking) how do you decide which ones to keep?

Comment: I always want to keep the longest period (i.e. the period containing the embedded periods). If two periods are exactly the same I choose a random as it is a duplicate.

Comment: Since you've been on the site for a while, I'm not flagging this question for "no effort", but your question doesn't include enough detail for us to help you. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. [SO - How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: np. I will add further details to my question

Comment: @Klelund see revised answer. I've added case for exact match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rough outline of query. It selects instead of delete so that you can see what gets deleted:

```
SELECT *
FROM testdata todelete
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM testdata tokeep
    WHERE
        todelete.start_date >= tokeep.start_date AND
        todelete.end_date <= tokeep.end_date AND
        todelete.rn <> tokeep.rn AND (
            todelete.start_date > tokeep.start_date OR
            todelete.end_date < tokeep.end_date OR
            todelete.rn > tokeep.rn
        )
)
```

The subquery selects rows that ***fully*** contain the outer row. If an exact duplicate of start-end dates is present i.e. row1 fully contains row2 and vice-versa then the one with higher id is selected.

[Variation of the above example using LEFT JOIN to display containing rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=6fb1833b4619a6846f08b6d74ad9cb17)

Comment: It works as intended. In the LEFT JOIN variation I've added "WHERE tokeep.rn IS NULL" to only return row number 1. Maybe switch the names of the table aliases for clarification (?). Which perform better - sub-select or left join variation? Thank you.

Comment: Since the objective is to delete the rows I wouldn't worry about performance. The answer uses `WHERE EXISTS` to select _contained_ rows. The `LEFT JOIN` example in the fiddle is there to _visualize_ how rows are matched (displays contained/todelete rows along with container/tokeep). You can rename the aliases to anything you like. `LEFT JOIN` vs `EXISTS` performance is debatable but it is claimed that `EXISTS` is faster.